# Warning: imagedestroy(): 7 is not a valid Image resource

Tags: gd, ооп, php

Php5. Есть примерно вот такой класс изображения c примерно вот таким методом:

```
class graphic{
 private $image;
 private $width;
 private $height;
 function __construct(...){
  $this->image=imagecreatetruecolor(...);
 }
 ...
 function resize($width,$height){
  $temp=imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
  imagecopyresampled($temp,$this->image,
   0,0,0,0,
   $width,$height,
   $this->width,$this->height
  );
  $this->image=$temp;
  imagedestroy($temp);
  ...
 }
}
```

Я создаю временную картинку, в неё копирую ресайзнутую картинку а потом заменяю мою исходную картинку ресайзнутой временной.
Проблема возникает с уничтожением временной картинки. Почему-то после того, как я присвоил исходной картинке идентификатор ресайзнутой временной - временную ресайзнутую уничтожить не удаётся:

```
Warning: imagedestroy(): 7 is not a valid Image resource
```

вардамп же $temp говорит, что $temp - resource(7) of type (gd)
Вот весь код класса, если надо: https://gist.github.com/lowpolybrain/5891996

**Хотелось бы знать, что происходит и почему такой варнинг.**

Comment: Потому что нужно уничтожать обе картинки, а не присваивать так, как делаете вы.

Comment: @lampa поподробнее, пожалуйста?

Наверное, я как-то неправильно понимаю значение слова "Resource". Сколько себя помню, всегда ресайзил именно так. Это и сейчас работает. Но в классе почему-то значение временной переменной меняется на что-то, чего не понимает функция imagedestroy.
Зачем уничтожать обе картинки, если с одной из них мне ещё работать дальше? Как тот факт, что я не "уничтожаю обе картинки, а присваиваю" относится к варнингу вообще?

Буду благодарен за метод ресайза картинки без создания временной, если он существует, пользуясь только средствами gd и php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сорри за вчерашний ответ, фигню написал. В общем пишут, что идентификатор теряется и уничтожить картинку нельзя. Ну и фиг с ней. Просто проверяйте, существует ресурс или нет. Ну и работать с картинкой лучше через `gd`, там и качество картинки на выходе хорошее и всякие плюшки есть.

А по вашему вопросу класс небольшой накатал:

```
class Image {
    private $source = false, $temp = false;

    /**
     * hook file
     */
    public function __construct($image) {
        if(!$info = getimagesize($image)) {
            throw new Exception("error image");
        }

        $createFunc = 'imagecreatefrom' . strtolower(str_replace('image/', '', $info['mime']));
        $this->source = $createFunc($image);

        return $this; //->source = $createFunc($image);
    }

    /**
     * resize file
     */
    public function resize($width, $height, $proportions = true) {
        if(!$this->source) {
            throw new Exception("error image");
        }

        if(!$proportions) {
            $ratio = $height / imagesy($this->source);
            $width = imagesx($this->source) * $ratio;
        }

        $this->temp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); 
        imagecopyresampled($this->temp, $this->source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, imagesx($this->source), imagesy($this->source)); 
        $this->source = $this->temp;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * save
     */
    public function save($filename, $type = 'jpeg') {
        $info = imagejpeg($this->source, $filename);

        if(is_resource($this->temp)) {
            imagedestroy($this->temp);
        }

        if(is_resource($this->source)) {
            imagedestroy($this->source);
        }

        return $info;
    }

    /**
     * hook
     */
    public static function hook($image) {
        $className = get_called_class();
        return new $className($image);
    }
}

Image::hook('11.jpg')->resize(50, 50)->save('22.png', 'png');
```

Comment: Спасибо! Любопытный подход.

Ну, я собственно через gd и работаю, но без пересоздания объякта каждый раз. Теперь вот просто метод для ресайза написал, как у вас.

Сейчас мне пришло в голову, что я затупил: временную картинку можно не уничтожать, ведь все равно моя переменная существует только в контексте метода и после выполнения должна собираться сборщиком мусора.

Comment: @Andrienko ну да, вы правы)